# How to get a json object as column values using postgresql?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, group-by

I have a data like below

```
id | customer  | region   | circle
----------------------------------
 1 | airtel    | tn       | c1
 2 | reliance  | ap       | c2
```

I am expecting the json output like below using PostgreSQL

JSON

```
[
    {"id":"1_airtel","parent":"#","text":"airtel"},
    {"id":"1_airtel_tn","parent":"1_airtel","text":"tn"},
    {"id":"1_airtel_tn_c1","parent":"1_airtel_tn","text":"c1"},
    {"id":"2_reliance","parent":"#","text":"reliance"},
    {"id":"2_reliance_ap","parent":"2_reliance","text":"ap"},
    {"id":"2_reliance_ap_c2","parent":"2_reliance_ap","text":"c2"}
]
```

Comment: `2_def_PCode2_20` seems like a really strange value for a "price". What not use the real values in the JSON object?

Comment: updated valid data and json values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a lateral join to generate the rows, and then json function `to_jsonb()` to turn them to object. The final step is aggregation:

```
select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(v)) res
from mytable t
cross join lateral (values
    (
        concat_ws('_', id::text, customer), 
        '#', 
        customer
    ),
    (
        concat_ws('_', id::text, customer, region), 
        concat_ws('_', id::text, customer), 
        region
    ),
    (
        concat_ws('_', id::text, customer, region, circle), 
        concat_ws('_', id::text, customer, region), 
        circle
    )
) v(id, parent, text)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e3d43ee5b8c250d31141fa1d73864267)**